# How can I parent a new button to the channel box in Maya using PySide?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, maya

I have a very basic understanding of PySide. I'm hoping to parent a button to the existing Channel Box. However I'm not sure where to start outside of getting the main Maya window. (But I'm not even sure this is correct):

```
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore
from shiboken import wrapInstance
from maya.OpenMayaUI import MQtUtil

channelBox = wrapInstance(long(MQtUtil.findControl('mainChannelBox')), QtGui.QWidget)
```

Comment: Just one button?  Where do you want the button to show up?  On top of the channel box, or somewhere on the edge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Messing up with Maya's UI can be a difficult task, there are two ways to do so.
First is to use `maya.cmds` to add widgets to Maya's UI. The second one is to wrap, just like you did, a Maya widget in a Qt class.

The is a similar question here: [How do I parent new, user-created buttons inside the Graph Editor window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33926047/how-do-i-parent-new-user-created-buttons-inside-the-graph-editor-window/)
I answered with `maya.cmds` code only and there is an other answer that might interest you as well using PySide.

Here is a solution:

```
nbIteration = 0
def getChildren(uiItem, nbIteration):
    for childItem in cmds.layout(uiItem, query=True, childArray=True):
        try:
            print "|___"*nbIteration + childItem
            getChildren(uiItem + "|" + childItem, nbIteration+1)
        except:
            pass
getChildren("MayaWindow|MainChannelsLayersLayout", nbIteration)
```

If you run this code, this will give you the name on the widgets contained in the `Channel Box / Layer Editor`

```
ChannelButtonForm <-- This is the form containing the 3 buttons on the top-right 
|___cbManipsButton
|___cbSpeedButton
|___cbHyperbolicButton
ChannelsLayersPaneLayout <-- This is the layout containing the channel box and the layer editor. A paneLayout has a splitter to resize his childrens.
|___ChannelBoxForm 
|___|___menuBarLayout1 
|___|___|___frameLayout1
|___|___|___|___mainChannelBox
|___LayerEditorForm
|___|___DisplayLayerUITabLayout
|___|___|___DisplayLayerTab
|___|___|___|___formLayout3
```

Depending on where you want your button to be snapped, you'll have to choose a layout as parent for your button.

In this case, I'm placing a button on the top-left part of the Channel Box/Layer Editor, on the same level as the 3 checkboxButtons.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

cmds.button("DrHaze_NewButton", l="HELLO", p="MayaWindow|MainChannelsLayersLayout|ChannelButtonForm")
```

As you didn't tell us where you want your button to be placed, you'll have to edit your question if you want something more appropriate.

Comment: This is great. Thank you! I'm also trying to parent a button inside the Graph Editor and Outliner. Using the above command as `getChildren("graphEditor1Window|", nbIteration)` doesn't seem to work though.  It says it can't find the Graph Editor, although `cmds.lsUI` says it exists.

Comment: Try this: `getChildren("graphEditor1Window|TearOffPane", nbIteration)` You need to pass a layout to the `getChildren` function.

Comment: And for the Outliner: `getChildren("sequenceEditorPanel1Window|TearOffPane", nbIteration)`

Comment: Thanks @DrHaze! Here's a pickle I didn't think about: with this current setup, the window has to already exist to insert new UI buttons, etc. into one of the forms. What's the best way to approach inserting the buttons in when a new GraphEditor window is created?

Comment: As a short answer, I see two solutions here. First is to write a script that creates a custom Graph Editor as in my answer in the linked question. You'll have to call this script instead of going in `Window -> Animation Editors -> Graph Editor`. The second solution is risky and I recommand to do a backup of any files you are modifying. You can directly edit this file `C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2014\scripts\others\graphEditorPanel.mel` and this  function in particular `addGraphEditor` to add a button to the graph editor.

Comment: coming back to this after a hiatus. Are you aware of a way to parent to an existing button in the Maya UI? With the above, Maya threw an error when I tried. Would I have to do it in the Layout?